# Matlab: passing large arrays or loading from .mat file

Tags: matlab, performance, large-data

I want to use large arrays with 1.0e6 elements in other Matlab functions. Currently I am using small sized arrays and passing them as function input. I do not how much this passing of arrays going to affect the speed of my program when I use large arrays. It is also possible that I save these input large sized arrays as .mat file and then load them in other Matlab functions for use.

So, my question is: which way is faster? Saving the arrays in .mat file and then loading them in Matlab functions **or** passing them as function input.

Comment: Why not have a workspace variable that you use directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing them as inputs to your function is the fastest as Matlab passes variables by reference (until you change them - then it would make a copy)

Saving and loading from file will definitely be slower!

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, it will be (much) faster not to save the arrays.

What's more, you can learn more about matlab mechanisms here: http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/internal-matlab-memory-optimizations

As long as your function does not modify your large array, it will not affect the performance to pass it as an input of the function.